# Why is my XAML throwing me a Storyboard object reference error?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, mvvm

So I am trying to create a animation that will run when I click my button.
It's supposed to move "Box" to the right.

However when i try to run the application I get this error.

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Set property
>   'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an
>   exception.' Line number '48' and line position '6'.'
>
> Inner Exception InvalidOperationException: Must have a Storyboard
>   object reference before this trigger action can execute.

I am new to animations so I am not entierly sure why it's throwing that error.
I tried Googleing but I couldnt find any real solutions.
Seems as if it's a scope issue afaik.

Would it be better to create a resource file and use that?
I've heard of people doing so but I'm not sure how to do it.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WooImporter.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WooImporter"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="WooImporter" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="slideRight">
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                 From="0" To="100"
                                 Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid Column="0"
              Background="#272727">
            <StackPanel>
                <ToggleButton Height="30"
                              Content="Add Products"
                              FontSize="18"
                              Foreground="White"
                              Style="{DynamicResource MenuToggleButtonStyle}"
                              x:Name="MenuButton1"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Column="1">
            <StackPanel Width="100"
                        Height="100"
                        Background="#212121"
                        x:Name="Box"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>



    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton"
               x:Key="MenuToggleButtonStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"></Setter>
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">     
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=MenuButton1}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource slideRight}"/>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>


</Window>
```

Comment: Have you tried with `StaticResource`?

Comment: @Rekshino Yep, I've tried that as well

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected it was a scope issue.
I moved the style inside the stackpanel

```
<Grid Column="1">
            <StackPanel Width="100"
                        Height="100"
                        Background="#212121"
                        x:Name="Box">

                <StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=theMenuButton}" Value="True">
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slideRight}" />
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Static Resource will do the trick but remember that Storyboard must be higher in resource hierarchy than StackPanel style. I mean you should move Storyboard to Window.Resources or StackPanel style to Grid.Resources. StoryBoard must be before StackPanel style. Then To StackPanel Style add RenderTransform Setter. In StoryBoard.TargetProperty you should add `(TransformGroup.Children)[0]` to show which element you want to transform in TransformGroup.

```
 <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="slideRight">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation
                    AutoReverse="True"
                    RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                    From="0"
                    To="1000"
                    Duration="0:0:0.3" />
            </Storyboard>
        </Storyboard>

        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=MenuButton1}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slideRight}" />
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
```